# Convert mp3 to ogg vorbis

Tags: mp3, ogg

Is there a command-line utility to convert mp3s to ogg vorbis that I can install with apt-get?

Alternatively, is there an extension for nginx so I can point it to a directory with mp3 files and have it serve ogg files on the fly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Debian, a quick search with aptitude showed me the packages mp32ogg and dir2ogg. Have a look, maybe they do what you need.

Answer (score 54):

`ffmpeg` (or more likely the fork `avconv` if you're using Debian or Ubuntu - these instructions *should* apply equally to both, though nobody knows how far apart they may drift in the future) should be in the repositories of your distro.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -c:a libvorbis -q:a 4 output.ogg
```

To do a whole directory full of MP3s:

```
for f in ./*.mp3; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:a libvorbis -q:a 4 "${f/%mp3/ogg}"; done
```

Recursively, with `find`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.mp3' -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "$0" -c:a libvorbis -q:a 4 "${0/%mp3/ogg}"' '{}' \;
```

Set the output quality by adjusting the value of `-q:a`: for this codec the range is 0-10 and higher gives better quality.

On older versions of `ffmpeg`, you may need to use `-acodec` and `-aq` instead of `-c:a` and `-q:a`.

Of course, converting from one lossy format to another is not ideal; but such is life.

Comment: For the quality parameter, a higher number gives better quality.
See here: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/TheoraVorbisEncodingGuide

Comment: Super - duper, thank you. Very useful in cases like this https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/4687

Comment: Confirmed: using those params with avconv does indeed work. Great answer.